# Compare two or more files and print only those lines from 1st file which contain words which aren't present in second file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have the following issue that I'm trying to solve in bash/sed/awk (Useful one-line script).

Compare two or more files and print only those lines from 1st file which contain words (patterns) which aren't present in second file in the same name, preserving the order in which they occur and ignore case sensitive. (gosh, sound so complex and stupid... I don't know how to put it in another words).

I have two different files (file1, file2) contaning a list of information like the following:

file1

```
Agents In The Court / No Love For The Empire
Mercenary Armor
Solo Han WB
Obi-Wan's Journal
Obi-Wan's Lightsaber
No Questions Asked
Do, or do Not
Strike Blocked
```

file2

```
Agents In The Court / No Love For The Empire BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Special Cards)    
Mercenary Armor BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Device)
Obi-Wan's Journal BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Device)
No Questions Asked BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Special Cards)
Do, Or Do Not BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Defensive Shield)
Strike Planning BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Effect)
Alter (Obi-Wan) WB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Used Interrupt)
Solo Han BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Human and Human-Like Characters)
Combined Attack BB -> (LiGHT SIDE -- Lost Interrupt)
```

Result should be like this:

```
Solo Han WB
Obi-Wan's Lightsaber
Strike Blocked
```

I would be grateful for any help (complete solution, tip, link to similar issue, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as file2 is not too large, either of these will work in bash:

```
while read x; do if [[ -z "$(grep -Fi "$x" file2)" ]]; then echo "$x"; fi; done < file1

cat file1 | while read x; do if [[ -z "$(grep -Fi "$x" file2)" ]]; then echo "$x"; fi; done
```

Overall, read each line in file1 and grep for it in file2, printing the line only when no match is found.

In more detail, `while read x; do ...; done < file1` reads one line at a time from file1 into the variable x.  The `"$(grep -Fi "$x" file2)"` searches file2 for a line containing the contents of `$x`, evaluating to an empty string when no match is found.  The `-F` flag tells grep to search for a fixed string, so it won't treat the contents of `$x` as a regular expression.  The `-i` flag says to ignore case while searching.  The test `-z` evaluates to true if its string argument is empty (i.e., grep found no match).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there exists an one-liner; you will have probably to work some temporary files.  Idea:

```
# just some boilerplate for handling temp files
t=`mktemp -d -t sort.XXXXXX`
trap "rm -rf $t" EXIT

# add two columns: file-id + line and sort by 3rd field (real data)
nl -ba -nln < file1 | sed -e 's/^/1 /' | sort -k3 >$t/file1
nl -ba -nln < file2 | sed -e 's/^/1 /' | sort -k3 >$t/file2

# get unique lines, filter these from file1, sort by line and give out data
uniq -f 2 $t/file1 $t/file2 | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 3-
```

(Untested; there might be needed some fixes regarding field delimiters).

Script above requires some more tools than sed + gawk but should work on recent GNU systems.

Answer (score 0):

something that is simple which should fit your needs is the built in diff

```
diff file1 file2
```

will print out all of the lines that are different between the two files

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
awk -f print.awk file1
```

where `print.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    while (getline < "file2")
        line[i++]=toupper($0)
}

{
    for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if (index(line[j],toupper($0))) { 
            f=1; break
        }
    }
    if (!f) print
    f=0
}
```